# html form arrays how to store into php array not including null elements

Tags: php, html

Storing an array submitted from forms stores elements with null values. Is there a way to store only non null fields into the php array?

$_SESSION['items'] = $_POST['items'];

is my current code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should take a look at [array_filter()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php). I think it is exactly what you are looking for.

```
$_SESSION['items'] = array_filter($_POST['items']);
```

Comment: it worked without the isset. amazing some of php functions make life so easy. Thanks buddy!

Comment: Right, I forgot about the automatic conversion and about the fact that empty form values are not NULL but empty strings.

Answer (score 3):

```
# Cycle through each item in our array
foreach ($_POST['items'] as $key => $value) {
  # If the item is NOT empty
  if (!empty($value))
    # Add our item into our SESSION array
    $_SESSION['items'][$key] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @[Till Theis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139586/html-form-arrays-how-to-store-into-php-array-not-including-null-elements/1139615#1139615) says, [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) is definitely the way to go. You can either use it directly, like so:

```
$_SESSION['items'] = array_filter($_POST['items']);
```

Which will give you all elements of the array which does **not** evaluate to false. I.E. you'll filter out both NULL, 0, false etc.

You can also pass a callback function to create custom filtering, like so:

```
abstract class Util {
    public static function filterNull ($value) {
        return isset($value);
    }
}

$_SESSION['items'] = array_filter($_POST['items'], array('Util', 'filterNull'));
```

This will call the filterNull-method of the Util class for each element in the items-array, and if they are set (see [language construct isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)), then they are kept in the resulting array.